# How to affect each element accroding to changing its row in angular5

Tags: angular, typescript

There are a list of objects that are iterated into grid of html by `ngFor` in angulare5 like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let entity of objectList;">
    <td> 
           <select [(ngModel)] = "entity.type">
                <option value="1">fix</option>
                <option value="2">floaty</option>
           </select>
    </td>
    <td> 
           <input type="text" value="entity.name">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to disable the `<input>` element of **each row** where its `<select>` element contains the floaty value and vice versa, it is enable when selected fix value.

How is it possible in typescript and angular5?

Comment: can you add objectList data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="text" value="entity.name" [disabled]="entity.type === '2'">
```

Comment: value should be like value="{{entity.name}}" otherwise it will simply print entity.name

Comment: That's not part of the question and it's an assumption (although you're probably right), and the correct syntax would be `[value]="entity.name"`. Interpolation is for inner text, not for attributes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use disabled property as like below.

Based on condition you specify the input will be disabled.

`<input [disabled]="entity.type==='2'" type="text" value="{{entity.name}}">`